# How to make sure a resource is pulled from server, not cache?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, caching, kendo-ui, href

The situation is this, I have a website that manages project outlines, users can upload PDFs to a pop up window, and then can click a link on the profile section of the project outline to see their PDFs on another pop up window.

Currently, if you upload a PDF that is replacing an old one, the browser will still show an old version of the PDF. I figured out that what is shown is a cached version of that PDF. The PDFs must maintain a consistent name (An outline of a project called X, will always be called "Outline X.pdf")

I was looking for a way to make sure that what is shown is ALWAYS pulled from the server. I don't need to pull the entire page from server, only certain resources.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set headers as follow to prevent caching :

```
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

You can also append a random querystring (like timestamp) to the filename.

Comment: How would I pull the correct image if I'm using a timestamp on the filename?

Comment: you add it as querystring : thefile.pdf?1426698099

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you're using since you didn't provide any code, so I can't give you any code, but generally the most common strategy to bypass caching is to append some string (often the current timestamp) on the end of the url. So instead of getting "/Outline%20X.pdf", get "Outline%20X.pdf?1426697196", where 1426697196 = the current timestamp.